# this.fireEvent not working extjs3

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I'm building my own class with extjs 3 (license issue)

```
Ext.ux.MyClass = Ext.extend(Ext.Container, {

       initComponent: function() {       
                this.button = new Ext.Button({
                                       scope:this,
                                       text:'my button', 
                                       handler: function() {
                                                     alert(0);
                                                     this.fireEvent('myevent');
                                       }
                });

                this.addEvents('myevent');
       }    
});


//in the code:

var obj = new Ext.ux.MyClass(...);

obj.on('myevent', function () {alert(1);});
```

The event was not fired the code does not give error I can see the Alert(0) but not Alert(1);

I tried the listener but also not working and the this.fireEvent returns true.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of ExtJS 3 are you using? 3.0, 3.1 or 3.4?

If it's 3.4 then it seems to work for me. I've added a little bit of extra code just to get the button to render but it seems ok to me.

The final code I'm using is:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.ux.MyClass = Ext.extend(Ext.Container, {
        initComponent: function() {
            this.button = new Ext.Button(
            {
                renderTo: document.body,
                scope:this,
                text:'my button', 
                handler: function() {
                    alert(0);
                    this.fireEvent('myevent');
                }
            });

            this.addEvents('myevent');
        }

    });

    var obj = new Ext.ux.MyClass();

    obj.on('myevent', function () {alert(1);});
});
```

Check out the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/J9YcL/

I'm running in Chrome if that makes any difference.

Comment: FYI, using renderTo for components inside containers isn't a good idea. Instead it should be a child item. Also, in your code you're not calling the parent initComponent.

Comment: Many thanks, yes the problem with the version I'm using ExtJs 3RC1 with 3.4 and up it works fine